# What is the convention when writing short if-else statements: is it ok to put the Condition and the Statement in one single line?

Tags: c#, if-statement

Is it more readable to have very short if-statements on a single line (i.e. the Condition and the Statement are in one line without braces), or more readable if you start a new line with "{}"? What is the more common/conventional way of writing it?

```
if   (p1.button1) p1M.runPressed = true;
else              p1M.runPressed = false;
if   (p2.button1) p2M.runPressed = true;
else              p2M.runPressed = false;
if   (p3.button1) p3M.runPressed = true;
else              p3M.runPressed = false;

if (p1.button1)
{
  p1M.runPressed = true;
else
{
  p1M.runPressed = false;
} 
if (p2.button1)
{
  p2M.runPressed = true;
else
{
  p2M.runPressed = false;
}    
if (p3.button1)
{
  p3M.runPressed = true;
else
{
  p3M.runPressed = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is slightly more readable ONLY if it's a single if statement with no else clause and only a single line afterwards.

The problem with your case is that you have an else clause afterwards, which makes it slightly harder to read in this case because everything is so smushed together.

However, there is a better solution to what you're doing:

```
p1m.runpressed = p1.button1;
p2m.runpressed = p2.button1;
p3m.runpressed = p3.button1;
```

This is exactly the same result, but it's even easier to read than an if statement.